# How to reference a nested model als foreign key in djongo

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I'm experimenting with [Djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/) right now: 
Is there a possibility to reference the djongo nested models in another model as a foreign key?
Or how would you deal with this structure in djongo?
Clinic 1:n Wards - 
Ward 1:n Cases (The cases should still be in their own collection.)

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
...
    wards = models.ArrayModelField(model_container=Ward, null=True,)
...

class Case(models.Model):

 ward = models.ForeignKey(
        'clinic.ward', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    ...

class Ward(models.Model):
    clinic = models.ForeignKey('Clinic', related_name='wards', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Case(models.Model):
    ward = models.ForeignKey('Ward', related_name='cases' on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rewise in the way of **looking NoSQL**, its **not** necessary to keep **relation** between objects, may be its even better to duplicate data (embedding).

If you are sure to make relation, and you really need the relation [here](https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-reference-field/) is how you can do it in django using djongo.

I guess you'll find out in the first steps to remove the relation and embed what is necessary.